# how to pass data from one fragment to an other if both are visible at a time

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments in a activity .one has edit field and second has `textview` .both are visible at time. I have to enter text into edit field and that text should be displayed on the second fragment which a `textview`. I have one solution , i can make static textview in secodn fragment but i think it is not best way to do that.Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Fragment [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

```
Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.
```

So i would suggest something like this:
 You have two fragments and one associated activity

**Code for Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    //On create stuff .....
    @Override
public void onButtonPressed(String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayOutTwo Obj=(LayOutTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_2);
     Obj.setMessage(msg);
}
}
```

**Code For Layout 1:**

```
Button but=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
     but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonListener.onButtonPressed("Message From First Fragment");
        }
    });
```

**Code For Layout 2:**

```
 void setMessage(String msg){
    TextView txt=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText(msg);
}
```

This how you can easily pass data between fragments using its associated activity.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, AsyncTask for what? for passing data?No , if the above answer helped you, please take a moment to mark it correct. Thanks